# Computing the 2-electron Reduced Density Matrix (2RDM) using QED

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-electrodynamics, density-operator, quantum-chemistry

So in quantum chemistry there is this concept of the 2-electron Reduced Density Matrix (2RDM), denoted here as $\Gamma$. It is defined, more like a function than a matrix, as the ridiculous integral shown in Eq. \eqref{eq:gamma_definition}

\begin{equation}
\tag{1}
\label{eq:gamma_definition}
\Gamma(\mathbf{r}_1, 
       \mathbf{r}_2;
       \mathbf{r}_1'
       ,\mathbf{r}_2'
       ) = 
N(N-1) 
\int_{\mathbf{r}_3,
      \mathbf{r}_4,
      ...,
      \mathbf{r}_N}
\Psi(\mathbf{r}_1,
     \mathbf{r}_2,
     \mathbf{r}_3,
     ..., 
     \mathbf{r}_N
     )
\Psi^*(\mathbf{r}_1',
       \mathbf{r}_2',
       \mathbf{r}_3,
       ...,
       \mathbf{r}_N
       )
~\mathrm{d}\mathbf{r}_3 
 \mathrm{d}\mathbf{r}_4
 \mathrm{d}\mathbf{r}_5 
 ... 
 \mathrm{d}\mathbf{r}_N
\end{equation}

where $N$ is the number of electrons and the terms $\mathbf{r}_i$ are the position of each of the $N$ electrons. I have often seen this expression being defined as the *position space* formulation of the 2RDM so presumably there is a non-position formulation hiding somewhere. Maybe a momentum formulation since in quantum mechanics the two things are never more than a couple Fourier Transforms away from one another.

Anyway, $|\Gamma(\mathbf{r}_1,\mathbf{r}_2;\mathbf{r}_1',\mathbf{r}_2')|^2$ represents the probability of finding electron $1$ at position $\mathbf{r}_1$ and electron $2$ at $\mathbf{r}_2$ given that they *were* at $\mathbf{r}_1'$ and $\mathbf{r}_2'$ respectively. So it is the probability of a *transition*, shown in the figure below. The function $\Gamma$ assigns a probability *amplitude* to events such as this one.

[image]

A probability amplitude is the complex number that, once squared, gives the probability of the event taking place. The particular shape of $\Gamma$ changes from system to system because $\Psi$ is given by the Hamiltonian of the system, which changes with the number and types of particles in the system.

In 1951, at a Summer Conference in Chalk River, mathematician John Coleman explained to an audience of physicists that because electrons are indistinguishable from one another and only interact via pairwise potentials, then the energy of any atom or molecule could be expressed as a linear functional of the $\Gamma$.

There are a number of practical advantages of using the $\Gamma$ instead of $\Psi$ as the fundamental unknown in the system and I won't discuss details here. But the problem is that although we can compute $\Gamma$ from $\Psi$ using Eq. \eqref{eq:gamma_definition}, the way to compute $\Gamma$ without reference to $\Psi$ is still, as far as I am aware, an open problem with no definitive solution but with many good ones, each with their own drawbacks and footnotes attached.

#### Two-Electron Scattering

My research on the topic allowed me to skim over a number of ingenious solutions to this particular problem which, to be frank, were so advanced that I could not conclude whether or not they had any relation to this particular approach that I will be suggesting.

This investigation also led me down a rabbit hole involving keywords such as "second quantization", "probability amplitude", "transmittance" and "tunneling" and "two-particle interactions" until I eventually stumbled upon this:

[image: two-electron scattering]

As far as I am aware, that is a Feynman diagram that represents one of the possible virtual interactions that go into the calculation of the two-electron scattering probability amplitude. This one in particular is a very significant contribution to the total amplitude because it is such a simple interaction.

For no other reason other than the fact that this looks a lot like the type of phenomenon that the 2RDM describes, I thought that if physicists have worked out the two-electron scattering problem, maybe I could use their solution and tweak it to write down the 2RDM, even if just an approximate or an asymptotic form.

The fit would not be neat because, as far as I know (not very far, I must warn all of you), the QED two-electron scattering is supposed to be computed for electrons in vacuum, but the 2RDM is computed for two electrons under the influence of a static electrostatic potential given by the stationary nuclei to which the electrons are bound as well as the interactions with the rest of the electrons which, I presume, would have to be taken into account somehow (maybe as a mean field, idk).

So now I am completely out of my depth. If before I was considering a conundrum in the unfamiliar 2RDM formulation of quantum chemistry (which is not mainstream at all) now I am looking at a solution that lies far afield in QED territory, entirely out of my grasp or expertise. So I decided to pose this question to the physics community to see whether any of this makes sense, or if that solution can be written down the way I intend it.

So here is my question: **Is it possible to use QED formalism to write $\Gamma$ directly as a modified solution to the two-electron scattering problem? Or, barring that, to at least arrive at half-solution such an equation that solves for $\Gamma$ or a limit or an integral that does not involve $\Psi$?**

I am aware that the answer to the question can simply be "no" but I would appreciate answers that could justify the details of the matter. The *why* it is not possible. These details matter to me and could give further insight into the issue, which at this point would be greatly appreciated.

#### Caveats

- I am using here the transmittance of electrons in 3D space, but these transitions need not be through space, these could be transitions between some two eigenstates in a basis set, at least as far as I know. The mathematics of the 2RDM formulation can be a bit thick and I have just been exposed to this way of doing theoretical chemistry.